# How can I train Multiple Projects at a time in RASA NLU

Tags: rasa-nlu

Is it possible to train multiple projects at a time in RASA NLU using single config file?

Or how can I configure one rasa core domain with multiple RASA NLU projects and access them?

If anybody needs any extra info Please comment will update my question.

Regards

Comment: No it is not possible, sadly. RASA 0.11.3 uses twisted so at the max you can send sequential requests.

Comment: Can you look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816506/7177029) this may help you

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no option for Rasa Core to route between various Rasa NLU instances. You would have to run multiple Rasa Core instances and connect these to different Rasa NLU instances.

In Rasa 1.0 Rasa Core and Rasa NLU were merged into the `rasa` package, which means both components are trained as one model.